# I have time 00:07:35.000000 in string format. How to change this to time format in bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, date-format

```sql
SELECT ride_time, CAST (ride_time as INTERVAL) as ride_time_hr
```

ride_time -> str 00:07:35.000000

I am expecting **00:07:35**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `PARSE_TIME` function:

```sql
SELECT ride_time, PARSE_TIME("%H:%M:%E*S", ride_time) as ride_time_hr
```

Output:

[image]

More info:

- `PARSE_TIME`: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#parse_time
- Format elements: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/format-elements#format_elements_date_time